# Ionic default positioning

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I’m looking at a Ionic tutorial that is a year old, and I made with it a basic page HTML page with Ionic components :

```
<body>
    <ion-app>
        <ion-header>
            <ion-toolbar color="primary">
                <ion-title >Budget Planner</ion-title>
            </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>

        <io-content>
            <ion-card>
                <ion-card-header>New Expense</ion-card-header>
                <ion-card-content>
                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-label position="floating">Expense Reason</ion-label>
                        <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>
                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-label position="floating">Expense Amount</ion-label>
                        <ion-input type="number"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-card-content>
            </ion-card>
            
        </io-content>
        
        <ion-footer>
            <ion-toolbar>
                <ion-title>Footer</ion-title>
            </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-footer>
    </ion-app>
</body>
```

[The result is this :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3VSW.jpg)

I've written HTML before and usually, it starts from the top. Here my content begins from the bottom (when I added the footer, it moved to being in the middle).
Note : there's no css or anything that I've added to make so and in the tutorial I'm following, it isn't like it is for me

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is . Your screenshot shows the outpout I would expect reading your html example. What is the expected output ?

Comment: The expected output is the card being at the top not floating in the middle. I'm only asking because in the tutorial, the result wasn't like mine

Comment: So the problem is that the `<ion-card>` is not being at the top but floats in the middle.

Comment: Yes, it's the fact that it float in the middle and that without the footer it sticks to the bottom. I don't think it's normal

Comment: Where is the tutorial you were following ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2ga-iXS5i4 - from 1:23:00 you can see the result of the code I entered. It's only a year old but I keep finding outdated things